# WordPress disable the hover animation on product listings

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to remove the hover animation on the product listing, When I place the mouse over a product listing it display some buttons to add to cart or add to the wishlist, and a transparent background is appearing as well. I want to hide these elements and display the product as it is.

An example can be found here, http://test.techvoip.it/staging/categoria-prodotto/monopattini/

I'm using Woocommerce and I'll be glad if someone can find me some sort of a solution.

Comment: Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you need to include the relevant code in your question so that we can see what it is doing and be able to help.

Comment: So you want to disable the Hover animation that is triggered when you move the mouse over a product? a simple CSS code should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert this CSS code into the custom CSS setting.

```
.vgwc-item .ma-box-content:hover .vgwc-image-block a:before, .vgwc-item .ma-box-content:hover .vgwc-image-block a:after {
    height: 0!important;
}

.vgwc-item .ma-box-content:hover .vgwc-image-block .vgwc-button-group {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Try it and let me know if it does the trick for you.